# how to enable Javascript in the HttpURLConnection

Tags: javascript, java, android

i am write a code for access the sever php file and to do find and sort data from the server.... the code works the is no error, when i am using the wamp server but i am change local host in to sever there show a message

"This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support"

this is code i am used for access the sever side php file...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timelist);
    Intent datafmto = getIntent();
    rsltlist =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.rsltlist);
    frm = datafmto.getExtras().getString("from");
    to = datafmto.getExtras().getString("to");
    Toast.makeText(this, frm + to, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new asd().execute("http://www.some severname.com/test.php", frm, to);
}
public class asd extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<models>> {
    StringBuffer buffer= null;
    BufferedReader red = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    @Override
    protected List<models> doInBackground(String... params) {
        frm= params[1];
        to = params[2];
        JSONObject json =new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("from",frm);
            json.put("to",to);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(json));
        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.connect();
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(String.valueOf(json));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(json));
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            red = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line=red.readLine())!= null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String out = buffer.toString();
            System.out.println(out);
            JSONObject timing = new JSONObject(out);
            JSONArray jarray = timing.getJSONArray("times");
            List<models> timelist =  new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                JSONObject lastobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                models mod = new models();
                mod.setRoute(lastobj.getString("route"));
                mod.setStart(lastobj.getString("start"));
                mod.setStop(lastobj.getString("stop"));
                timelist.add(mod);
            }
            return timelist;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(con!=null){
                con.disconnect(); }
            try {
                if (red!=null){
                    red.close(); }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: kindly check the headers required here, your new server might have imposed some new configuration that you should check first